# Firebird equivalent to MySQL table partitioning

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm working with Firebird 2.5.  I have used MySQL table partitioning in the past to help optimize very large tables by creating partitions based on year.  I would like to do the same thing, if possible, in Firebird but I'm having trouble finding any documentation.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, can you please point me toward some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird does not support table partitioning, which is also why you can't find anything about it in the [documentation](https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-rdbms/).

Depending on the exact performance problem you're trying to solve and the queries you use, choosing your indexes well may already solve part of the problem.

Comment: thank you for confirming.  One additional question, in your opinion, would throwing the database onto a SSD drive greatly improve the performance?  We are also checking to make sure our indexes are optimized, but this idea has been brought up too.

Comment: @Phil Yes putting it on a SSD will usually improve performance, see also https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/45-ways-to-speed-up-firebird-database/ and https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/firebird-performance-degradation-tests-myths-and-truth/

Comment: thanks!  That's exactly where I got the idea in the first place :)